# Meteor publications in server folder

Tags: meteor, meteor-react, meteor-collections

I have a collection named `LibraryItems` which is available on both client and server side.

*api/libraryitems/libraryitems.js*

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const LibraryItems = new Mongo.Collection('libraryitems');
export default LibraryItems;
```

Instead of an `if (Meteor.isServer) {..}` publication in this same file, I would like to have a server folder with the specific publications:

*api/libraryitems/server/publications.js*

```
import LibraryItems from '../libraryitems';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.publish('LibraryItems.pub.all', function () {
  return LibraryItems.find({});
});
```

But somehow, against my expectations, this publication is not available...

**update**

This is my subscription code (meteor+reactjs):
*./imports/ui/Library.js*

```
import LibraryItems from '../api/libraryitems/libraryitems';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
...
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('LibraryItems.pub.all');
  var libraryitems = LibraryItems.find().fetch();
  return {
    libraryitems: libraryitems
  }
}, Library);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'this publication is not available?'

Comment: I have edited my original answer now that you posted your container code

Comment: @Sean, that was a typo, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to register the publications in `mains.js`:

`import '../imports/api/libraryitems/server/publications';`

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting LibraryItems as a default export, that means when you import it you don't need curly brackets around it.

Change your import to:

`import LibraryItems from '../libraryitems';`

Also, clean up the publication code slightly:

`return LibraryItems.find({});`

**EDIT**

Now that you have posted your subscription code as requested, I see that you are subscribing to the publication with a different name.

Change to:

```
Meteor.subscribe('LibraryItems.all');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok, then you must have a problem elsewhere. Can you post your subscription code and helper code?